# Actually there was zero interactions with this mock error?

Tags: junit, mocking

I am trying to write test case but stuck with this error. How to fix this error ?

```
@Override
    public boolean isDuplicateSystemDetail(SystemFormBean systemFormBean){
        List<BrmSystem> list = systemDao.isDuplicateSystemDetail(systemFormBean);
        if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(list)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Test
    public void isDuplicateSystemDetail_Should_Return_True(){
        List<BrmSystem> list = new ArrayList<BrmSystem>();
        BrmSystem brmSystem = new BrmSystem();
        SystemFormBean systemFormBean = new SystemFormBean();
        brmSystem.setSystemName("Test");
        list.add(brmSystem);
        when(systemDao.isDuplicateSystemDetail(systemFormBean)).thenReturn(list);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably SystemFormBean class doesn't override equals(). So when isDuplicateSystemDetail(systemFormBean) invokes, it has another object of this class as a parameter which is not the same as the one you've created manually (by default Object.equals() compares memory adresses which would be false in your case).

Try to override equals() to compare by f.e. actual fields of SystemFormBean or rewrite "when" clause as
systemDao.isDuplicateSystemDetail(Mockito.any(SystemFormBean.class))